# Problema al insertar datos en base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, modal, insert

Este es el codigo de mi formularo , cuando selecciono las variables que luego serviran para hacer el select individual de cada tabla , luego debo insertarlas en una tabla final , basicamente lo que necesito es tomar los datos de 3 tablas diferentes y luego insertarlos en una tabla final

```
                        <?php
                        // incluye la conexión
                        include_once('connection.php');

                        $database = new Connection();
                        $db = $database->open();
                        try {
                            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM certificado';
                            foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
                        ?>
                                <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['id_certificado']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['nom_estudiante']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['curso']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['entrenador']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['expedicion']; ?></td>



                                <td>
                                        <a href="#edit_<?php echo $row['id_certificado']; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Editar</a>
                                        <a href="#delete_<?php echo $row['id_certificado']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Eliminar</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <?php include('edit_delete_modal.php'); ?>
                                </tr>
                        <?php
                            }
                        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                            echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
                        }
                        //cerrar conexión
                        $database->close();
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include('add_modal.php'); ?>
```

aqui se reciben los datos del formulario y se guardan en variables para luego utilizarlas , 
es mi duda  , se puede reslizar las consultas asi o debo usar otro comando para hacer las consultas en un solo ciclo

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $trainer = $_POST['trainer'];
    $curso = $_POST['curso'];
    $expe = $_POST['expedicion'];



$query_estudiante = "SELECT * FROM nacional where nombre_completo ='$name'";
$query_entrenador = "SELECT * FROM entrenador where nombre_entrenador ='$trainer'";
$query_curso = "SELECT * FROM curso where nombre_curso ='$curso'";

$ejecutar_est= mysqli_query($conexion,$query_estudiante);
$ejecutar_tra= mysqli_query($conexion,$query_entrenador);
$ejecutar_cur= mysqli_query($conexion,$query_curso);


while ($rowe = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar_est)) {
    while ($rowt = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar_tra)) {
        while ($rowc = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar_cur)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO certificados
            (id_certificado,duracion_curso, expedicion, nivel, nom_estudiante, cedula, entrenador, firma, resolucion, curso,cargo_profe) VALUES 
        ('5'
        ,$rowc[duracion]',
        '$_POST[fecha]',
         'alto',
        '$rowe[nombre_completo]',
        '$rowe[cedula]',
        '$rowt[nombre_entrenador]',
        '$rowt[firma]',
        '$rowt[resolucion]',
        '$rowc[nombre_curso]',
            '$rowt[cargo_entrenador]')";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? a) No inserta registros b) Inserta de más c) Otro... Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega todos los detalles.

Comment: listo asi esta mejor¡??

Comment: Si las primeras dos consultas devuelven solo un resultado, basta con leerlas y usar solo el ciclo de cursos.

Comment: no, cada consulta devuelve un valor en especifico ejemplo una devuelve 2 columnas de 3 que tiene la tablas otra 3 de 5 y otra 2 de 4

Comment: La primera consulta devuelve un solo registro para estudiante, la segunda un solo registro para entrenador... sobran los dos primeros ciclos.

Comment: No la primera consulta me devuelve 2 datos del entrenador , el para eso lo meti en un while para seleccionar con row el resultado especifico de cada tabla